# How to align content bottom on Bootstrap 4 col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following code for a footer:

```
  <div class="container"> <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"> 
         © BusinessName 2017.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"> <br>
        <a href="/blog"> Blog </a> <br>
        <a href="/blog"> FAQ </a> <br>
        <a href="/blog"> About </a> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <p><strong>Contact</strong> <br> contact@businessname.com <br> more info bla bla <br> more more more info</p>
      </div>
    </div>   </div>
```

I am trying to align all content on bottom line, I've tried some things but nothing works... any bright ideas?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use `align-items-end` from the [new Bootstrap 4 flexbox utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#align-items)...

```
<div class="container">
    <hr>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            © BusinessName 2017.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="/blog"> Blog </a>
            <br>
            <a href="/blog"> FAQ </a>
            <br>
            <a href="/blog"> About </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <strong>Contact</strong>
            <br> contact@businessname.com
            <br> more info bla bla
            <br> more more more info
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/GXTF43toS9

Also, auto margins work inside flexbox. There you could use `mt-auto` (margin-top:auto) to "push" the col-* to the bottom.

Answer (score 55):

Row vs col, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/zyh5a4rb/

For all the columns in the entire row use `align-items-end` **on the row**

```
<div class="row border align-items-end">
    <div class="col"> 
        A (row align-items-end)
        <br/>
        A<br/>
        A<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        B
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        D
    </div>
</div>
```

For a single column us `align-self-end` **on the col**

```
<div class="row border">
    <div class="col"> 
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        B<br/>
        B<br/>
        B<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end">
        C (col align-self-end)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        D
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most concise and beautiful solution

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Is there a way to align in the middle?